# help understanding the recurrence relation of an algorithm

Tags: recurrence-relation, java

I have the following code which I have to figure out the recurrence relation, but I am having a bit of a trouble understanding what the algorithm does exactly.

```
Interesting-Product(A[1..n])

if n = 1 then return

for i := 1 to n/3   do 
    A[i] = A[i]*A[i+(n/3)]  
 
Interesting-Product(A[1..n/3])

 for j := (n/3) + 1 to   2n/3   do
      A[j] = A[j]*A[j+(n/3)] 

 Interesting-Product(A[1..n/3])
```

I'm taking an algorithms class and having trouble understanding the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to parse this procedure, which we denote by $P$ for short.

The input to $P$ is an array $A$ of length $n$.

If $n = 1$, then we immediately quit.

Otherwise, we perform $n/3$ multiplications, call $P$ on an array of length $n/3$, perform $n/3$ more multiplications, then call $P$ on the same array of length $n/3$ again.

The procedure isn't doing anything interesting – the exercise is only asking you to express the running time of $P$ as a recurrence relation. We think of the running time of $P$ as a function $T(n)$, where $n$ is the length of the input to $P$. The recurrence relation should just follow the description above, using big O whenever appropriate (this should have been explained in class).

If you're not sure how to work out the recurrence relation, I suggest you review the class material. It would be counterproductive to solve this elementary exercise for you – the goal of such questions is for you to get a handle on the basics, and the only way to accomplish that is for you to actually solve the question on your own.